# Can't update from Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently downloaded Ruby, and am trying to create a simple app. I'm using RVM, and am positive I downloaded version 2.0.0 -- indeed, ruby -v confirms this. However, when I try to use Rails, it tells me that I have Ruby 1.8.7 installed. Anyone have any clue what's going on? I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.7, for reference.

Edit: I've run rvm use 2.0.0, and have every reason to believe I *should* be running Runy 2.0.0. Indeed, when I try use 1.8.7, it tells me it's not installed!

Comment: have u tried rvm use version ?

Comment: Try setting the default: http://rvm.io/rubies/default

Comment: Yup, the default is set to 2.0.0 but I still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running the rails server like this.

```
sudo rails server
```

What you need to do is run it like this,

```
rvmsudo rails server
```

That will use the RVM ruby version instead of the computer default.